# How to specify loading an assembly in an app domain neutral manner

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm-2011

Is there a way to indicate to the CLR to load an class library assembly as domain neutral?
The use case is MSCRM plugins in which each plugin is loaded in a separate app domain and needs the services of a "utility" library which can be quite large (10+ megs) and it would be neat to be able to load a single copy of the code page that is shared across all app domains, thus reducing the memory footprint of the overall process

Answer (score 1):

You can load a assembly as domain neutral, you need apply the attribute LoaderOptimization as MultiDomain. Check this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43wc4hhs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to know how do that.

Comment: The attribute seems to works only on the Main method and hence will not work for class libraries